# Customize Minitest output to growl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, guard, growl

In my rails app I am using:

- guard
- guard-minitest
- growl

when a test runs in the background:

[image]

I get this from Growl:

[image]

Great to know that at least one test failed.  Any way to add that summary that reports the number i.e. 2 failures etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the behavior by modifying [Guard::Minitest::Notifier.notify](https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest/blob/b7946a0b4e24ab625cb8cb04efe3ca1116ccac9e/lib/guard/minitest/notifier.rb#L27):

```
require 'guard/compat/plugin'

module Guard
  class Minitest < Plugin
    class Notifier
      # ...
      def self.notify(test_count, assertion_count, failure_count, error_count, skip_count, duration)
        message = guard_message(test_count, assertion_count, failure_count, error_count, skip_count, duration)
        image   = guard_image(failure_count + error_count, skip_count)

        # title: was just 'Minitest results'
        Compat::UI.notify(message, title: message, image: image)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The title 'Minitest results' is most likely just a cludged placeholder. This example sets it to the same output as you get in the CLI but you can really do whatever you want here.

You would preferably do this by forking the gem and setting your gemfile to pull from your fork.

```
gem 'minitest-guard', github: 'yourusername/minitest-guard'
```

Comment: I am following this but unclear.  I am adding this as a module in `/lib`?  I think a local patch is easier right now than a fork.  Still unclear how `Running: test/controllers/api_controller_test.rb` is being passed to Growl.  That is the first output in guard when the test tiggers.

Comment: If you are monkeypatching it you need to make sure your monkeypatch is required at the correct point in loading your test suite which is really as much of a PITA as forking it. If you don't want a public fork you can set your gemfile to pull from a local path as well. https://rossta.net/blog/how-to-specify-local-ruby-gems-in-your-gemfile.html

Comment: The more I dig the more I think this is not worth it.  Growl is retired and when a test fails I am usually looking to the output anyway.  Will accept the answer - Thanks.